# Facebook graph api to filter feed with text alone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch the group post but i need only text feed from that group. If i call the `https://graph.facebook.com/{group_id}/feed?` it is fetching all the post in that group.

Ex:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "story": "test 1 created a private event",
            "updated_time": "2018-09-03T13:50:25+0000",
            "id": "345_543"
        },
        {
            "story": "test 2 shared a post",
            "updated_time": "2018-09-03T09:17:44+0000",
            "id": "123_321"
        },
        {
            "message": "fetch only feed with this message tag",
            "story": "test 3",
            "updated_time": "2018-08-31T10:14:12+0000",
            "id": "567_765"
        },
```

In this response the 3rd array is the text feed. So is there a way to filter only the text feed from the group.

I know that i can customise it after fetching the result set but i need to implement it with the facebook graph api?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such filtering available for the feed endpoint. (No such thing has been implemented, due to performance concerns.)

You will have to fetch all posts, and then filter out what you need/ don’t need yourself on your end.